# how to create a power bi measure that filters out a code based on a id

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

I have a table that has multiple of the same codes and each code can have a different id to it as follows

```
Code | ID
45   | 2
45   | 5
45   | 8
45   | 7
21   | 1
21   | 9
```

i want to count the code that doesnt have and ID of 2 or 8 against it. However for example because the code of 45 has and id of 2 or 8 i want to ignore that code and only give me the code 21 which will be a count of 1

i have tried

```
Unsuccessful = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[code]), FILTER('Table', NOT('Table'[ID] in {2,8})))
```

but the above is giving me a count of 2, when i want it to be 1. How do i ignore **that code** if it has 2 or 8 already present against it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is almost correct:

```
Unsuccessful = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Tables'[code]),FILTER('Tables', NOT(CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Tables'[Code]), ('Tables'[ID] in {2,8})))))
```

The inner part returns the codes we want to exclude.

```
CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Tables'[Code]), ('Tables'[ID] in {2,8})
```

First consider the inner part. CALCULATETABLE generate for us table from first argument based on filter in second). VALUES('Table'[Code]) -> produced distinct list of values from column, because of lineage it remember source (more: here https://www.sqlbi.com/?s=lineage). This part return code for which we find ID 2 or 8 (in this example Code = 45).

When we have a list of codes that we want to exclude, everything is simple. We just put FILTER inside CALCULATE. The first argument of FILTER is our base table, second - filter its self. Here we put table as a filter and because of Lineage, the engine "knows" relationship between data.

[image]

Comment: i tried it now,but its still giving me the same count of 2

Comment: I copied your sample data to my test model and I get the results as expected. How do you use this measure?

Comment: @scott this DAX formula is working fine, cross-check your DAX again.  User msta42a Can you explain this formula once, please.

Answer (score 0):

I have try your question with increase the amount of data, at the end the result is same as your expect, accept if help :)

Here is the table for the raw data

[image]

I apply this measure to count the distinct expect contain 2 or 8:

```
Measure 2 = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Sheet1[Code]),FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[ID] = 2 || Sheet1[ID] = 8))
```

Scorecard result

[image]